# "Append" in a while loop not working, Python

Tags: python, oop

I want to add the last three items of the list "M.Carte" (length 40) in the list "self.CarteInMano", using a while loop:

```
class Mano:
    def __init__(self,Giocatore,Dimensioni=3):
        self.Giocatore=Giocatore
        self.CarteInMano=[]
        self.Dimensioni=Dimensioni

    def Pesca(self):
        a=0
        while a==self.Dimensioni:
            self.CarteInMano.append(M.Carte.pop())
            a=a+1
```

But, after:

```
M1=Mano(1)
M1.Pesca()
```

I get:

```
len(M.Carte)
40
len(M1.CarteInMano)
0
```

Why "Pesca" doesn't do what it has to do?

Comment: It doesn't look like `while a==self.Dimensioni:` is ever true. Did you mean `while a<=self.Dimensioni:`?

Comment: It should be `a<=self.Dimensioni`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
while a==self.Dimensioni:
    self.CarteInMano.append(M.Carte.pop())
    a=a+1
```

this will only run when `a == 3` you should try this instead:

```
while a<=self.Dimensioni:
    self.CarteInMano.append(M.Carte.pop())
    a=a+1
```

The reason is that in the first code a will only run when it is EQUAL to dimensioni, and since it start at 0 and not 3 it will never be equal, and skips the code. If you use `<=` instead, you now run the code while a is less than or equal to 3

***NOTE***

If you want to get 3 elements, then use just `<` instead, using `<=` will get you 4 elements (since it works for 0, 1, 2, and 3).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a noob, ouch.